# Using recursion to solve the subset sum problem

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic

I want to calculate the number of subsets of the array `A = [2, 1, 1, 4]` that sum to `2`. There are 2 ways: `(A[0])` and `(A[1], A[2])`. My code for computing this is:

```
 def W(number, index):
     A = [2, 1, 1, 4]
     if number < 0 or index < 0:
          return 0
     elif number==0:
          return 1
     else: 
          return W(number, index-1) + W(number - A[index], index)
```

Right now, when I call the function with `W(2,3)`, I get `4` instead of 2. My problem is that my code also calculates the possibility `(A[1], A[1])` and `(A[2], A[2])`. Is there any way to fix it while still using recursion?

Comment: See that when you use a number from an array (decrease your number by it) you **don't** want to reuse it again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `W(number - A[index], index)` should be `W(number - A[index], index - 1)`; otherwise, you allow for the possibility of double-counting an element in your subset sum.

Here is a code snippet that fixes this issue. For each element, we decide whether or not to add it to our sum. If the element allows our target to reach `0`, we add `1` to our total count of possibilities, then recurse to see if there are any other ways to reach the target without adding the element we're currently examining:

```py
A = [2, 1, 1, 4]

def W(number, index):
     if number < 0 or index < 0 :
          return 0
     elif number - A[index] == 0:
         return 1 + W(number, index - 1)
     else: 
          return W(number, index - 1) + W(number - A[index], index - 1)
          
print(W(1, 3)) # Prints 2
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be 2 for ``W(4, 3)``, and 2 for ``W(5, 3)``?

Comment: I think the order of the conditions can be changed. The first check is `if number == 0: return 1` and then `elif number < 0 or index < 0: return 0`. This also works, but not sure about other test cases

Comment: `W(1, 3)` prints 1, but I think it should be 2 because `A[1]` and `A[2]` works.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you'll need to store the original target in that case. I'll fix shortly, I have to hop off for a bit.

Comment: Alright, edited.

Comment: For your first point: the original code doesn't have this problem (especially the case you mentioned `W(2,0)`), because in the original code the index never changes when we use a number from an array. So the call to `W(2,0)` branches to two calls - `W(2, -1)` and `W(0, 0)`. The second branch returns `1`. **Note:** I'm saying about the original code of the author.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but using `W(number - A[index], index)` doesn't correctly represent the recursive structure to the problem anyway.

Comment: I've edited once again to clarify that the bug is one related to the recursive structure. Thank you for pointing out this issue in the explanation. :)

Answer (score 2):

This code seems to work for cases finding sums of 1..8:

```py
A = [2, 1, 1, 4]

def W(number, index):
     if number == 0:
          return 1
     elif number < 0 or index < 0:
          return 0
     else:
         return W(number, index-1) + W(number - A[index], index - 1)
```

Testcases:

```py
print(W(1, 3))
print(W(2, 3))
print(W(3, 3))
print(W(4, 3))
print(W(5, 3))
print(W(6, 3))
print(W(7, 3))
print(W(8, 3))
```

Output

```
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
1
```